# how to add wp-user fields to front-end form

Tags: customization, profiles

I've found all kinds of information on how to add user-meta fields to a front-end form. However, I can't find how to add email and the change password.

I found the form fields in user-edit.php, but what to use in place of update_user_meta()?

Comment: Neither email nor password are usermeta fields...are you trying to make a frontend form that allows people to update their email/password?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to take the code I found in user-edit.php and put it into a front-end form (which is only available to the loggin-in user). But I'm pretty sure I can't use update-user-meta() since the email and password fields are in the wp-user table.

Comment: See my response for a basic idea of how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should point you in the right direction:

```
function updateUser($newPassword = '', $newEmail = ''){
    $update = array();
    if(!empty($newPassword))
        $update['user_pass'] = $newPassword;
    if(!empty($newEmail))
        $update['user_email'] = $newEmail;
    if(!empty($update)){
        $update['ID'] = wp_get_current_user_id();
        return wp_update_user($update);
    }
    return;
}
```

See [`wp_update_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) for more info on how that function works.  You should also verify the source of the post data with a [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).